# How to Remove some character while using eval function in infopath?

Tags: eval, infopath

Currently I am getting values like below

by using below formula in infopath.

```
eval(eval(Delegate, 'concat(., "; ")'), "..")
```

Result:-

```
i:0#.w|manol\sp_testuser2; i:0#.w|manol\sp_testuser1; i:0#.w|manol\kaeel;
```

We need to remove the " i:0#.w|manol\ " character from the result.

Like :-

```
sp_testuser2;sp_testuser1;kaeel
```

I tried with substring inside eval function but it showing error in formula.

Ex:-

```
 eval(eval(substring(Delegate, 17), 'concat(., "; ")'), "..")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. You can nest another eval. So it would be:

```
eval(eval(eval(Delegate, 'substring(.,17)'), 'concat(.,";")'),"..")
```